# У меня не проходит нормально стандартизация признаков

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, scikit-learn

У меня не проходит нормально стандартизация признаков.

Есть DataFrame `df11`, провел его стандартизацию признаков с типом `float64`. 
На выходе получил новый DataFrame, но множество параметров отстандартизировались таким образом, что стали не числа а `NaN`.

Что делать?

[image: не получается нормально стандартизация]

Comment: стандартизация прошла успешно, вот тока нормально стандартизированные значения поставить в дф не может

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Причина "ошибки" в том, что вы создаете DataFrame с нормализованными значениями *с индексными значениями по-умолчанию*. В вашем исходном DataFrame значения индекса имеют пропуски:

```
0, 1, 2, 4, ..., 9993, 9995
```

Pandas во время присваивания объекта типа DataFrame делает выравнивание по индексу и по столбцам.

Поэтому в данном случае можно либо создать DataFrame, использовав значения индекса из исходного DF:

```
df11[feature_names_for_stand] = pd.DataFrame(stand_features, 
                                             columns=feature_names_for_stand,
                                             index=df11.index)
```

либо присваивать Numpy ndarray (результат работы `StandardScaler`):

```
df11[feature_names_for_stand] = stand_features
```

т.к. у numpy.ndarray отсутствуют имена столбцов и `custom indexing`, то и выравнивание не имеет смысла.

Comment: большое спасибо за ответ

Comment: @КириллМаликов, всегда рад помочь )